# couldn't find out how to solve this algorithm problem

Tags: c, algorithm

I am beginner I tried so many times but I couldn't solve this problem I will be very pleased if you help me...

the question is:

1. Let x be an integer, and R(x) is a function that returns the reverse of the x in terms of its digits.
2. For  example , if x:1234 then R(x)=4321.
3. Let’s call a positive integer mirror-friendly if it satisfies the following  condition:   + () = ^2 ℎ
4. Write a program that reads a positive integer as n from the user and prints out a line for each of the first  n mirror-friendly integers as follows: x + R(x) = y^2
5. Example: If the user enters 5 as n, then the program should print out the following:

```
2 + 2 = 2^2
8 + 8 = 4^2
29 + 92 = 11^2
38 + 83 = 11^2
47 + 74 = 11^2
```

Here is the my code:

```
int
reverse(int num)
{
    int reverse,
     f,
     i;

    reverse = 0;
    i = 0;
    for (; i < num + i; i++) {
        f = num % 10;
        reverse = (reverse * 10) + f;
        num /= 10;
    }
    return reverse;
}

int
sqrt(int n)
{
    int i = 1;
    int sqrt;

    for (; i <= n; i++) {
        sqrt = i * i;
    }
    return sqrt;
}

int
main()
{
    int j = 1;
    int main_num = 0;

    for (; main_num <= 0;) {
        printf("Please enter a positive integer: \n");
        scanf_s("%d", &main_num);
    }
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= main_num; i++) {
        for (; j <= main_num; j++) {
            if (j + reverse(j) == sqrt(?)) {
                printf("%d + %d = %d\n", j, reverse(j), sqrt(?));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you allowed to convert the number to a string ?

Comment: I did it I guess.

Comment: Why to yo need the sqrt-function? And why to you multiply the indexes i in a loop ignoring the results with the exception of the last one?

Comment: I wanted to check if j+reverse(j) is equal to any perfect square number

Comment: What dies the `sqrt` function do, and how does it do it? Explain to your nearest [rubber duck](https://rubberduckdebugging.com/). If this doesn't work, test the function separately.

Comment: `sqrt(int n)` does `n*n` rather inefficiently.

Comment: I want to ask, is my only problem sqrt part ? The rest of the code is true ? and how can I do it more efficient ?

Comment: What is "_efficient_" for you? Does the program run too slow, or does it take too much memory?

Comment: I think in the beginning efficienity is less important. I need to learn how to make algorithms that works and I need help on it.

Comment: Fix one problem at a time...

Comment: Do you get the expected result, or no?

Comment: I know 9 is special, but generalizing takes a lot of number theory. I would probably compute the squares of integers _first_, and then take those and linearly do a subtraction and see if they are palindromic opposites.

Comment: The function name `sqrt` is extremely misleading  because it is not calculating a square root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few issues ...

1. `sqrt` does *not* compute the square root
2. `reverse` seems overly complicated
3. `main_num` (i.e. `n` from the problem statement) is the desired maximum *count* of matches and *not* the limit on `x`
4. Too many repeated calls to `sqrt` and `reverse`
5. No argument given to `sqrt`
6. The `if` in `main` to detect a match is incorrect.
7. `sqrt` conflicts with a standard function.
8. The variables you're using don't match the names used in the problem statement.
9. The `printf` didn't follow the expected output format.
10. Using a function scoped variable that is the same as the function is a bit confusing (to humans and the compiler).

---

Unfortunately, I've had to heavily refactor the code. I've changed all the variable names to match the names used in the problem statement for clarity:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifdef DEBUG
#define dbgprt(_fmt...)     printf(_fmt)
#else
#define dbgprt(_fmt...)     do { } while (0)
#endif

int
reverse(int x)
{
    int r = 0;

    for (;  x != 0;  x /= 10) {
        int f = x % 10;
        r = (r * 10) + f;
    }

    return r;
}

int
isqrt(int x)
{
    int y = 1;

    while (1) {
        int y2 = y * y;

        if (y2 >= x)
            break;

        ++y;
    }

    return y;
}

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    int n = -1;

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    if (argc > 0) {
        n = atoi(*argv);
        printf("Positive integer is %d\n",n);
    }

    while (n <= 0) {
        printf("Please enter a positive integer:\n");
        scanf("%d", &n);
    }

    int x = 1234;
    dbgprt("x=%d r=%d\n",x,reverse(x));

    int count = 0;
    for (x = 1;  count < n;  ++x) {
        dbgprt("\nx=%d count=%d\n",x,count);

        // get reverse of number (i.e. R(x))
        int r = reverse(x);
        dbgprt("r=%d\n",r);

        // get x + R(x)
        int xr = x + r;
        dbgprt("xr=%d\n",xr);

        // get y
        int y = isqrt(xr);
        dbgprt("y=%d\n",y);

        if (xr == (y * y)) {
            printf("%d + %d = %d^2\n", x, r, y);
            ++count;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here is the program output:

```
Positive integer is 5
2 + 2 = 2^2
8 + 8 = 4^2
29 + 92 = 11^2
38 + 83 = 11^2
47 + 74 = 11^2
```

---

**UPDATE:**

The above `isqrt` uses a linear search. So, it's a bit slow.

Here is a version that uses a binary search:

```
// isqrt -- get sqrt (binary search)
int
isqrt(int x)
{
    int ylo = 1;
    int yhi = x;
    int ymid = 0;

    // binary search
    while (ylo <= yhi) {
        ymid = (ylo + yhi) / 2;

        int y2 = ymid * ymid;

        // exact match (i.e. x == y^2)
        if (y2 == x)
            break;

        if (y2 > x)
            yhi = ymid - 1;
        else
            ylo = ymid + 1;
    }

    return ymid;
}
```

---

**UPDATE #2:**

The above code doesn't scale too well for very large `x` values (i.e. large `n` values).

So, `main` should check for wraparound to a negative number for `x`.

And, a possibly safer equation for `isqrt` is:

```
ymid = ylo + ((yhi - ylo) / 2);
```

Here is an updated version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifdef DEBUG
#define dbgprt(_fmt...)     printf(_fmt)
#else
#define dbgprt(_fmt...)     do { } while (0)
#endif

// reverse -- reverse a number (e.g. 1234 --> 4321)
int
reverse(int x)
{
    int r = 0;

    for (;  x != 0;  x /= 10) {
        int f = x % 10;
        r = (r * 10) + f;
    }

    return r;
}

// isqrt -- get sqrt (linear search)
int
isqrt(int x)
{
    int y = 1;

    while (1) {
        int y2 = y * y;

        if (y2 >= x)
            break;

        ++y;
    }

    return y;
}

// isqrt2 -- get sqrt (binary search)
int
isqrt2(int x)
{
    int ylo = 1;
    int yhi = x;
    int ymid = 0;

    // binary search
    while (ylo <= yhi) {
#if 0
        ymid = (ylo + yhi) / 2;
#else
        ymid = ylo + ((yhi - ylo) / 2);
#endif

        int y2 = ymid * ymid;

        // exact match (i.e. x == y^2)
        if (y2 == x)
            break;

        if (y2 > x)
            yhi = ymid - 1;
        else
            ylo = ymid + 1;
    }

    return ymid;
}

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    int n = -1;

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    setlinebuf(stdout);

    // take number from command line
    if (argc > 0) {
        n = atoi(*argv);
        printf("Positive integer is %d\n",n);
    }

    // prompt user for expected/maximum count
    while (n <= 0) {
        printf("Please enter a positive integer:\n");
        scanf("%d", &n);
    }

    int x = 1234;
    dbgprt("x=%d r=%d\n",x,reverse(x));

    int count = 0;
    for (x = 1;  (x > 0) && (count < n);  ++x) {
        dbgprt("\nx=%d count=%d\n",x,count);

        // get reverse of number (i.e. R(x))
        int r = reverse(x);
        dbgprt("r=%d\n",r);

        // get x + R(x)
        int xr = x + r;
        dbgprt("xr=%d\n",xr);

        // get y
#ifdef ISQRTSLOW
        int y = isqrt(xr);
#else
        int y = isqrt2(xr);
#endif
        dbgprt("y=%d\n",y);

        if (xr == (y * y)) {
            printf("%d + %d = %d^2\n", x, r, y);
            ++count;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In the above code, I've used `cpp` conditionals to denote old vs. new code:

```
#if 0
// old code
#else
// new code
#endif

#if 1
// new code
#endif
```

Note: this can be cleaned up by running the file through `unifdef -k`

Comment: Thank you so much. Your first code is easier to understand and I am trying to solve it in my mind. I am really grateful

Answer (score 0):

1. `for(;i<num+i;i++)`
   is equal to
   `for(; 0<num;i++)`
   or `for(; num;i++)` if we are working with positive values only.
   or even to `while(num)`
   So, we don't need variable `i` in reverse function.
2. We don't need cycle at all in sqrt function. Just `return n * n;` is ok. But it is not sqrt then
3. The last cycle is too strange. At least variable `j` is not initialized.